# How can I make my Java server being available from all over the world?

Tags: java, networking, server, client

I am new to all that networking stuff. I have recently been working on a client and a server in Java. 
The client connects to the server as it should and also gets a response from the server. Everything is working fine as long as client and server are running on computers in the same network. When I try to connect to the server from a computer that is not in the same network as the server the client just does not find the server.

What can I do so that the client can connect to the server from another network? And does that mean I can connect to the server from all over the world?

Here you can find my server code:

```
    package zwei;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    public static int Port = 55571;

    static ServerSocket ServerSocket;
    static Socket ClientSocket;

    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader in;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            handleConnection(Port);

    }


    static void handleConnection(int port) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Waiting for connections...");

        ClientSocket = ServerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to Client!");

        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ClientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while(true) {
            try {
                    char[] buffer = new char[200];
                    int AnzahlZeichen = in.read(buffer, 0, 200);
                    String message = new String(buffer, 0, AnzahlZeichen);
                    System.out.println("[Client] " + message); 

                    out.print("Dear Client, I got your message! [ -" + message + "- ]");
                    out.flush();

                    if (message.equals("DISCONNECT")) {
                        System.out.println("Client disconnected");
                        ServerSocket.close();
                        ClientSocket.close();
                        handleConnection(Port);
                    }
                }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Client disconnected");
                ServerSocket.close();
                ClientSocket.close();
                handleConnection(Port);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And here you can find the code of the client:

```
package zwei;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Client extends JFrame{

    static int port = 55570;
    static String ServerAdress = ""; //Here I put the IP-Adress of the computer the server is running on

    static Socket ClientSocket;

    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader in;

    JTextField EnterMessage;
    JButton SendMessage;

    Client(){
         this.setLayout(null);
         this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         this.setVisible(true);
         this.setResizable(false);
         this.setSize(700, 700);
         //this.setTitle("Vokabeltrainer");

         EnterMessage = new JTextField();
         EnterMessage.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 50);
         this.add(EnterMessage);

         SendMessage = new JButton("send");
         SendMessage.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 100);
         SendMessage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    SendMessageToServer(EnterMessage.getText());
                    ReceiveMessageFromServer();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }});
         this.add(SendMessage);
    }

    private void connectToServer(String ServerAdress, int port) throws IOException {

        try {
            this.ClientSocket = new Socket(ServerAdress,port);
            System.out.println("Successfully established a connection to the server on port " + port + " .");
            }

        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occured while trying to connect to the server!");
            System.out.println("");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void SendMessageToServer(String Nachricht) throws IOException {
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ClientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        out.print(Nachricht);
        out.flush();
    }

    private void ReceiveMessageFromServer() throws IOException{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
        char[] buffer = new char[200];
        int AnzahlZeichen = in.read(buffer, 0, 200);
        String message = new String(buffer, 0, AnzahlZeichen);
        System.out.println("[Server] " + message); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        Client client = new Client();
        client.connectToServer(ServerAdress, port);
        //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClientSocket.getInputStream()));


    }

}
```

Comment: That usually has nothing to do with Code but with network configuration. Either put it on a server with a public IP hosted somewhere or use port forwarding from your router to host it at home. Bear in mind that you need either a static IP address or a dynamic DNS to have it available all the time. Depending on your ISP your IP at home could change from time to time. Also make sure you configure your firewall so the application is allowed to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, every computer has an ip address and a port number and server is a type of computer. if you want to your application work, you should have a server that can run java or if you just need test you should have static ip for your computer.
This way, your client app always knows which port and which IP address should use to connect to your server app.
If you want to test and you do not want to pay for server or static Ip address, give Ip address and port from user in client app and I think that you can run your apps on 2 different computers, but worth mentioning that settings of your rooter may have impact on your connection.